# Delete lines with value below (or above) threshold

Tags: sed, awk, delete

My file looks like this:

```
AA  110 B   10   ..  BB  15   ... BBB 20   D   F   25   D   D
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F
AA  112 C    2   ..  BB   3   ... BBB  0   D   F    0   D   F
AA  120 D    2   ..  FF   3   ... FFF  3   D   F    3   D   D
```

I would like to delete lines containing a value =< 10 in any of the columns. I am aware of the use of `sed` and `awk '$3 !=< 10'` but this would only delete lines at the third field. Is there a way to tell qwk to consider all columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`perl` to the rescue

```
$ cat ip.txt 
AA  110 B   10   ..  BB  15   ... BBB 20   D   F   25   D   D
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F
AA  112 C    2   ..  BB   3   ... BBB  0   D   F    0   D   F
AA  120 D    2   ..  FF   3   ... FFF  3   D   F    3   D   D

$ perl -ae 'print if !(grep { $_ <= 10 && /^\d+$/ } @F)' ip.txt 
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F
```

- `-a` split input line on space and save to `@F` array
- `grep { $_ <= 10 && /^\d+$/ } @F` get all elements of `@F` array which are made of only digits and whose value is `<= 10`
- then print lines if grep returns `0`. The `()` around `grep` means it will return count of matches rather than elements themselves

Let's test another condition:

```
$ perl -ae 'print if !(grep { $_ < 10 && /^\d+$/ } @F)' ip.txt 
AA  110 B   10   ..  BB  15   ... BBB 20   D   F   25   D   D
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F
```

Certain conditions, like in this question, can be solved with `grep` too (which probably is faster than `perl` solution)

```
$ grep -vw '[0-9]\|10' ip.txt 
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F

$ grep -vw '[0-9]' ip.txt 
AA  110 B   10   ..  BB  15   ... BBB 20   D   F   25   D   D
AA  111 B   50   ..  BB  55   ... BBB 30   F   F   45   F   F
```

- `-v` lines other than matching pattern
- `-w` match whole words only

Comment: That works! Thanks! I particularly like the grep solution: clean and easy. What I want to do the same thing but just considering a range of columns, lets say, columns 10-15? I guess awk should work in this case.

Comment: for particular columns, change `@F` to `@F[9..14]` (index starts from 0)

Answer (score 7):

In `awk`, you can use something like `for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) { ... }` to loop over all fields on a line. With that, something like:

```
awk '{for(i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) { 
         if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $i <= 10) { next };
       } 
     } 1'  < input
```

`$i ~ /^[0-9]+$/` checks if the field is only digits, and then it's compared to `10`, moving to the `next` record (line) if smaller or equal to 10.

Answer (score 0):

this is for sed

```
sed -rn '/\b([0-9]|10)\b/!p' file
```